# Horizontal div slider javascript

Tags: javascript, slider

I need to create a JS-slider as in following image:
[image]

How do I create a slider like this?
How do you name something like this? can't find examples on internet/google.

Answer (score 1):

This is called as **Carousel**

Try using [Library](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

Your requirement is given in their demo.